# Itunes API Request

Tags: python, json, api, itunes

I am trying to make an API request to itunes to get songs by a particular artist and great a dictionary in JSON format with those songs. My below code is not returning any errors, but I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any help would be great. Also, I put comments next to some of the lines to help to further explain.

```
    import json
    import requests
    def get_from_itunes(artist,songs):
    base_url = "http://itunes.apple.com/search"
    params_dict = {"term":bon+iver, "entity": music}
    resp = requests.get(base_url, params=params_dict)
    structured_resp_text = resp.text
    python_obj_data_from_itunes = json.loads(structured_resp_text)
# the python object is a dictionary
    itunes_dict_keys = python_obj_data_from_itunes.keys() # These keys are lists
    for key in itunes_dict_keys:
        print key # it's unicode. I have no clue how to proceed from here.
# I should be getting a dictionary
# And then getting to the key Track Name

    file_obj = open("itunes_file.txt", "w") #wrote a file containing a JSON formatted string 
# and then pasted that into the JSON editor
    file_obj.write(python_obj_data_from_itunes + "\n")
    file_obj.close()

    return get_from_itunes()
```

Comment: Are you calling your function?

Comment: What is the expected and observed result?

Comment: @Klaus D. I am expecting to get data that shows a dictionary of songs by Bon Iver that are in JSON in a text file. Currently even when I print our the key for the itunes_dict_keys nothings is generated, I am not even getting a syntax error.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel try using this http://pythonhosted.org/python-itunes/